# project connect: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found 

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to install the following project [connect](https://github.com/dsyph3r/connect) on osx lion.

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://github.com/dsyph3r/connect
cd connect
git submodule update --init

php bin/vendors install
```

When I run the following command `php bin/vendors install` I get the following messages:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115

Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115

Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115
```

What did I miss?

P.S.

```
more app/config/parameters.ini
[parameters]
    database_driver="pdo_mysql"
    database_host="localhost"
    database_port=""
    database_name="connect"
    database_user=""
    database_password=""
    mailer_transport="smtp"
    mailer_host="localhost"
    mailer_user=""
    mailer_password=""
    locale="en"
    secret="xxxx"


more deps | grep FOSRest 
[FOSRest]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRest.git
[FOSRestBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle.git
```

Comment: The mailer_transport parameter is supposed to appear in your parameters.ini, and to be imported in you config.yml . Is it the case?

Comment: @greg0ire, I posted my app/config/parameters.ini. is it ok? what other things should I look at?

Comment: @greg0ire, I posted my app/config/parameters.ini and part of my deps file. As you can see the problem is about FOSRest and not mailer_transport. I made the same as you suggested in [FOSRestBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md)

Comment: I'm confused... wasn't the FOSRest problem supposed to be solved in the previous question? What is this now? It doesn't talk about the mailer_transport anymore. Did you check your config.yml for the mailer_transport import?

Comment: @greg0ire in the previous question I was wrong saying FOSRest problem has been fixed. Do you think `./app/config/config.yml` comes into play when I perform the command `php bin/vendors install`

Comment: No, I don't think so. Could you check whether the file holding the class sf is asking for exists?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status codes are already available in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`.

```php
//...
const HTTP_CONTINUE = 100;
const HTTP_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS = 101;
const HTTP_PROCESSING = 102;            // RFC2518
const HTTP_OK = 200;
const HTTP_CREATED = 201;
const HTTP_ACCEPTED = 202;
//...
```

You can use it like this:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations,    
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 *
 * @Annotations\View(
 *   template = "QuoteBundle:Quote:new.html.twig",
 *   statusCode = Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
 * )
 *
 */
```